# AJAX content change plus small change effect

Tags: javascript, ajax

im trying to change an AJAX Code to add a small change effect so users can see that something happend on screen, cause the change of the content is hidden and its hard to notice that only some numbers have changed

```js
function changeBox(post) {
    if (http != null) {
        http.open("POST", 'ajaxchangebox.php', true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!http) {
                return;
            }
            if (http.readyState == 4) {
                 document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = http.responseText;;
                }
        }
        http.send(post);
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with Javascript/AJAX. The kind of effect itself is not important. it should be something flashing, short change of colour or something like that.

Thanks for your help
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help: [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

usage:

```
document.getElementById("box").classList.add('bounce animated')
```

You need to add a listener to catch animation end event:

```
var onDone = (function(){
    var elm = document.getElementById('box');
    var animateEndName = function () {
        var i,
        el = document.createElement('div'),
        mapping = {
                'animation': 'animationend',
                'OAnimation': 'oanimationend', 
                'MozAnimation': 'animationend',
                'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd'
        }

        for (i in mapping) {
            if (el.style[i] !== undefined) {
                return mapping[i];
            }
        }
    }();

    elm.addEventListener(animateEndName, function(){
        elm.classList.remove('flash', 'animated');
    });

    return function(result){
        elm.innerHTML = result;
        elm.classList.add('flash', 'animated');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. butte that doesnt work. I changed it to document.getElementById("box").className += " flash animated" but that only works once. How can i remove the class?

Comment: I updated answer, please let me know if it still not works